# Remove an undefined element when converting an array into a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Practising through an exercise where you need to take all the elements in an array and make a string. I am aware that there is a simpler js method for arrays that can accomplish the task.

I keep getting an `undefined element` at the beginning of my string. I think it from using the `reverse()` method. Would like to know of other solutions with minor differences in my code.

```
let arrayLength = stringMe.length;
stringMe.reverse();
let myString;
for (;arrayLength >= 1; arrayLength--) {
  let charStorage   = stringMe.pop(); 
  myString = myString + charStorage;
}

console.log(myString);
```

The expected output should be `fox` but the actual output is `undefinedfox`

Comment: why do you reverse the array and pop the value, and get an ordered, b ut not reversed string?

Comment: You can remove the `.reverse()` call and use [`.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) instead of `.pop()`.

Comment: Hello Titus, I was wondering if there was a counterpart to the .reverse() method. Thank you for introducing me to the .shift() method. Hello Nina, since .pop() starts with the end element of the array, I had to reverse so it spells out "fox".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try initialize myString with empty string
`let myString = "";`

Comment: That was easy enough. Would you please care to explain?

Comment: Sure. Javascript variables are initialised to `undefined` if not assigned any value. And, when you try to concatenate non string value with a string it is first converted to string. In your case since the value is `undefined` it is converted to string`"undefined"`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot that they are initialised with the default value of "undefined" and should explicitly be set to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [0, 1, null, 2, "", 3, undefined, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,];

var filtered = array.filter(function (el) {
  return el != null;
});

console.log(filtered.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the missing initialization of the variable, you could omit reversing (that should do the algorithm) and take a `while` statement which checks the length of the array.

Then just add the popped character to the result string.

```js
var stringMe = 'fox'.split(''),
    myString = '';

while (stringMe.length) {
    myString += stringMe.pop();
}

console.log(myString);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your alternative approach. I have yet to reach while loops and I am unsure of the 3 dots in the array [... x].

Comment: it takes an [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables) and returns an array, the same as split('') for strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to complete the task with 1 line of code like this:

```
stringMe.reverse().join("");
```

```js
var stringMe = ["I ", "am ", "D.F. ", undefined];

var result = stringMe.reverse().join("");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there certainly are much better ways of doing this.  But if all you really want to do is fix your error, then all you need to do is initialize `myString` to the empty string.

If you don't initialize `myString`, then its initial value will be `undefined`.  Further problematic behaviour will stem from this.

On the first iteration through the loop, it will try to concatenate (with the `+` operator) `myString` with the first element of the array.  If the first element is `alpha` then that will result in `undefined` and `alpha` being combined to form `undefinedalpha`.  This happens because the `+` operator will coerce the value **undefined** into the string `undefined` so that it can be concatenated with the string `alpha`.  See [this longer explanation](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/).

To correct the problem, just make sure `myString` initially has the value `''` (the empty string).

```js
let stringMe = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie'];

let arrayLength = stringMe.length;
stringMe.reverse();
let myString = '';
for (;arrayLength >= 1; arrayLength--) {
  let charStorage   = stringMe.pop(); 
  myString = myString + charStorage;
}

console.log(myString);
```

#### A better way:  use `join`

I have to also submit that [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is, I think, the best solution.

Use `join` to concatenate all the items of the array together, using an empty string (`''`) as the separator between items.

e.g.:

```js
let stringMe = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie'];

let myString = stringMe.join(''); // separate each item with an empty string.

console.log(myString);
```

Result: `alphabravocharlie`

Comment: Hello Wyck. Thank you for the comprehensive explanation. I was also thinking of using a more crude approach, maybe just using ifs and functions, unsure if its possible. Will keep .join() in mind for future coding!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let stringMe = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie'];

let arrayLength = stringMe.length;
stringMe.reverse();
let myString = '';
for (;arrayLength >= 1; arrayLength--) {
  let charStorage   = stringMe.pop(); 
  myString = myString + charStorage;
}

console.log(myString);
```